# Configurar el máximo volumen en un equipo de sonido

Tags: configuración

Necesito un script para configurar el volumen máximo en un equipo de sonido, y pasar este código a través de una memoria *USB*, de manera que al insertarla, se ejecute automáticamente y se configure el valor dado.

Lo ideal, es que funcione en cualquier equipo de sonido.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código que hiciste? Este sitio no hace script, sino ayuda en los errores o a preguntas que se presentan. Ademas este sitio es en español. Podrías borrar la parte de ingles. Muchas gracias

Comment: @josego Ok gracias, pensé que aquí tal ves podrían ayudar con algo que quizá otras personas con mas conocimiento ya hayan realizado, aún no he realizado código sobre esto. Si me pudieran dar tips sobre como realizar esto, les agradecería.